# Can I Perform inheritance outside of the class in C++11?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, inheritance, c++11

Say I want to overload a function outside of my classes with different pointer types. Can I do this in C++11?

```
struct Bird;
struct Bear;

struct Animal {
    virtual Bird* AsBird() = 0;
    virtual Bear* AsBear() = 0;
};
struct Bird : public Animal{
    virtual Bird* AsBird(){ return this; }
    virtual Bear* AsBear(){ return NULL; }
};
struct Bear : public Animal{
    virtual Bird* AsBird(){ return NULL; }
    virtual Bear* AsBear(){ return this; }
};

void Print(Animal* a){
    cout << "I don't know what animal this is!" << endl;
}

void Print(Bear* b){
    cout << "That's a bear!" << endl;
}

void Print(Bird* b){
    cout << "That's a bird!" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    Animal* a = new Bear;

    Bear* bear;
    Bird* bird;

    if (bear = a->AsBear()){
        Print(bear);
    } else if (bird = a->AsBird()){
        Print(bird);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This code works, but it's absolutely awful. I have tried playing around with templates and auto, but the compiler doesn't want anything to do with my evil experiments. Is there a legitimate way of doing this?

Comment: `AsBear()`...are you just re-implementing `dynamic_cast`?

Comment: A method returning NULL on error is always a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 2):

What you did is **overloading** the `Print` free function by changing the type of its parameter, there is no inheritance involved, and this is perfectly legal.

But you don't need it (or any dynamic_cast-like as you did) : What you should do is add a `virtual void Print() const = 0` in your `Animal` base class instead, and override it in each derived class.

**Example:**

```
struct Animal {
    virtual void Print() const = 0;
};

struct Bird : public Animal{
    void Print() const { cout << "That's a bird!\n"; }
};

struct Bear : public Animal{
    void Print() const { cout << "That's a bear!\n"; }
};

int main(){

    Animal* a = new Bear;
    a->Print();

    Animal* b = new Bird;
    b->Print();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a use case for the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).

```
struct Bird;
struct Bear;

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void Visit(Bird& x) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Bear& x) = 0;
};

struct PrintVisitor : Visitor
{
    void Visit(Bird& x) override { cout << "That's a bird!" << endl; };
    void Visit(Bear& x) override { cout << "That's a bear!" << endl; };
};

struct Animal
{
    virtual void Accept(Visitor& v) = 0;
};

struct Bird : public Animal
{
    void Accept(Visitor& v) override { v.Visit(*this); }
};

struct Bear : public Animal
{
    void Accept(Visitor& v) override { v.Visit(*this); }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Bear bear;
    Bird bird;

    PrintVisitor visitor;      

    Animal* a = &bear;
    a->Accept(visitor);

    a = &bird;
    a->Accept(visitor);
}
```

Of course, it might just be easier to make `Print` a virtual member function.

Answer (score 1):

As *quantdev* noted, the traditional way is adding a virtual function to your class hierarchy.

However, if you don't want to do it, you can use `dynamic_cast`, which was invented specifically for purposes like this.

```
struct Animal {
    virtual ~Animal() {} // base class must have a virtual method to use dynamic_cast
};

...

if (bear = dynamic_cast<Bear*>(a)){
    Print(bear);
} else if (bird = dynamic_cast<Bird*>(a)){
    Print(bird);
}
```

This is a little better than what you have: if you add another inheriting class, you don't have to change your base class; you must only change your `main` function and add a new printing function.

If this is still "awful", maybe you should make `Print` a virtual function.

Answer (score 0):

The `AsBear`, `AsBird` functions, you've simply reimplemented `dynamic_cast`.

As far as the overloads of `Print` goes, the simplest solution here is to make `Print` be a `virtual` function in the `Animal` hierarchy.

My recommended solution would be to use the visitor pattern. Since that's what it seems like you're trying to do by decoupling the `Print` function and the class hierarchy.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Bird;
struct Bear;

struct Animal {

  struct Visitor {
    virtual void operator()(const Bird *) const = 0;
    virtual void operator()(const Bear *) const = 0;
  };

  virtual void Accept(const Visitor &visitor) const = 0;

};

struct Bird : public Animal {

  virtual void Accept(const Visitor &visitor) const override {
    visitor(this);
  }

};

struct Bear : public Animal {

  virtual void Accept(const Visitor &visitor) const override {
    visitor(this);
  }

};

struct Print : public Animal::Visitor {
  virtual void operator()(const Bird *) const override {
    std::cout << "Bird" << std::endl;
  }
  virtual void operator()(const Bear *) const override {
    std::cout << "Bear" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  Bird bird;
  Animal *animal = &bird;
  animal->Accept(Print());
}
```